# DevOps Center - Promote fails. Where to see details?

Tags: devopscenter

I'm trying to promote a work item and it fails.  The only error I see is "4 tests failed".  Is there anyplace I can get details?  Logs of some kind?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the error details by accessing the deployment on the target org (Setup -> Deployment Status).